# why my gene IDs are not appearing as a column?

Tags: r

Why the column of my gene IDs has no name and is not listed in the data frame? I want to put a name on this column...

```
> dim(data_frame)
[1] 19947     3
```

I have 4 columns, not 3...

[image]

Comment: one is just row identifier. you can use tibble::rownames_to_column() then you shoul find 4 columns

Comment: These are row names and not a column. You can add the rownames as a column to the dataframe as `data_frame$new_col_name = rownames(data_frame)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably when you read a file the first column was recognized as row names and set as such. It could be a result of an empty column name. For `read.csv` you could control it by the row.names argument.

You want to use a step like that

```
data_frame$ID = rownames(data_frame)
rownames(data_frame) = NULL
```